# In the Harry Potter universe, is there a difference between magical objects and enchanted objects?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, magical-items

In other words, does the Harry Potter universe have both enchanted things (a normal object with a spell on it) and magical things (objects that are innately magical)?  For example, a magic fire-sword that can throw fire in people's faces is magical, but a normal sword that is enchanted so it is burning and able to throw fire in people's faces (my new favorite spell) is enchanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A magical object is one which is inherently magical in and by itself, whereas an enchanted item is one which has been intervened to become magical.**

**Magical Objects**
A magical object is magical in itself; nothing has been done to it to *become* magical, it just is.

For example:

- [Unicorn's Blood](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unicorn_blood)
- [Witches and Wizards](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wizardkind)
- [Mandrakes](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mandrake)

**Enchanted Objects**
Are objects which have had to have some magic *applied* to them, to become altered and magical.

Generally ordinary objects, such as:

- [The Ford Anglia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Ford_Anglia)
- [A Snitch](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Snitch) (and other Quidditch related equipment)
- [A Wand](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand)

Comment: Wands are vessels from which magic flows, I'm not so sure that any wand is actually magical. Wands are basicly salted water, good conductors of electricity... or magic in this case

Comment: Just thought of another magical object: Mokeskin!

Comment: The first enchanted object that popped into my mind, precisely because it's usually such a very mundane and _non_-magical object at base, would be **Portkeys**.